# How fast is the free Wi-Fi at Kiev airport?

Tags: airports, wifi, kyiv, kbp

Kiev Borispol's website [mentions](https://kbp.aero/en/infrastructure/free-wi-fi/) that there if free Wi-Fi throughout the terminals. How fast and reliable is this free Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Wi-Fi was surprisingly fast (6/6 Mbps, SpeedTest image below) and accessible reliably throughout the whole terminal.

[image: kiev airport wifi]

In 2017 it has also been comparably fast and reliable, with my friend reporting a 10 Mbps Speedtest.

Comment: Lol please don't tell me you travelled to the Kiev airport just to answer this question...

Comment: @celeriko +1, but no, I was just bored on a layover :)

Comment: That's some dedication right there!

Comment: @Criggie he is answering his own question so ...

Answer (score 6):

Its a bit hit and miss depending on where you sit. Sometimes it perfect, sometimes I have to reconnect every 2 minutes.